# I want to print a static variable inside my html using angualrjs

Tags: html, angularjs

id is a static variable called Benny inside my html.  I want to print id on the screen but am getting a blank.

```
<scheduled-event
              id1 = "Benny"
              event="event"
              ng-repeat="event in $ctrl.adherence.events">

     <h2>{{id1}}</h2>       
</scheduled-event>
```

Comment: You should expose more of the code. Is it from a `directive` or simply a normal html id attribute?

Comment: `id` needs to be defined in your controller (or be inside a ng-repeat scope) for you to be able to print it.

Comment: Please add more code to this so future readers can see the whole picture.  It's easier to understand a project when you see the bigger picture.

Comment: id is an html attribute

Comment: please provide a demo, it looks like you are passing your variable to a directive "scheduled-event". You cannot access a variable passed to directive in the HTML in this wat

Answer (score 0):

To put a static variable on scope, use the `ng-init` directive:

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app>
    <scheduled-event
        ng-init="id1='Benny'"
        event="event"
        ng-repeat="event in [1,2]">

      <h2>{{id1}}</h2>       
    </scheduled-event>
  </body>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS `ng-init` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).